# JavaScript or jquery trigger left arrow key press event (Simulate arrow key press)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, keydown, arrow-keys

I am trying to simulate the left and the right arrow key press in a text area within a rad grid control (Telerik).

I have a bug that is specific to the browser Firefox where the tab event(got this part fixed) and the arrow keys wont work. Every other browser works fine.

So as a workaround i want to simulate the arrow keys using JavaScript or jquery.

Below is what i have working with the tab event fix included. In addition to this I check if the key code 37 (this is the left arrow key) is pressed. At this point i want to simulate the left arrow press in the text area.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {   //tab pressed
        event.preventDefault(); // stops default action
    }
});

$('body').keyup(function (e) {

   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

   //Left arrow key press
   if (code == '37') 
   {
       moveLeft();// This does not trigger the left arrow event
   }

   //Tab button pressed
   if (code == '9') {
       //shift was down when tab was pressed focus -1
       if (e.shiftKey && code == 9) {                                    
           var focused = $(':focus');
           var inputs = $(focused).closest('form').find(':input');
           inputs.eq(inputs.index(focused) - 1).focus();
       }
       //tab was pressed focus +1
       else {
            var focused = $(':focus');
            var inputs = $(focused).closest('form').find(':input');
            inputs.eq(inputs.index(focused) + 1).focus();                                 
            }
   }      
});
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated

Comment: If you don't want to do this code yourself, you can use this library (https://craig.is/killing/mice) which I think might help you accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by moving the cursor back one space, below is the code I used to simulate the left arrow key press.

Note - To simulate right the key code is 39 and set the myval property to -1.

```
$('body').keydown(function (e) {

     var code = e.keyCode || e.which; //Find the key pressed

     if (code == '37') {

          e.preventDefault(); // stop default action
          var elementId = e.target.id;// get id of input text area                                     

          var el = document.getElementById(elementId),
          myval = 1 // set mouse cursor to move back one space
          cur_pos = 0;

          if (el.selectionStart) {
              cur_pos = el.selectionStart;
          } 
          else if (document.selection) {
              el.focus();

              var r = document.selection.createRange();
              if (r != null) {
                  var re = el.createTextRange(),
                  rc = re.duplicate();
                  re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
                  rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);

                  cur_pos = rc.text.length;
               }
          }

          if (el.setSelectionRange) {
              el.focus();
              el.setSelectionRange(cur_pos - myval, cur_pos - myval);
          }
          else if (el.createTextRange) {
              var range = el.createTextRange();
              range.collapse(true);
              range.moveEnd('character', cur_pos - myval);
              range.moveStart('character', cur_pos - myval);
              range.select();
          }
}
```

Comment: This code moves the caret from one position to previous or next. But when the caret goes beyond the visible area of textbox or textarea, the scroll to the updated caret position is not happening.